# Show that for every $v$ and $w$ with a propery $Qv=w$ and $Qw=v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $v,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|v\|=\|w\|.$ If $Q$ is the householder matrix for $u=\frac 1{\|v-w\|}(v-w)\implies Qv=w$ and $Qw=v$.

So I understood that the Householder matrix for an arbitrary vector, if I'm not mistaken, $Q=I_n-2uu^t$, so then our $Q$ will become:

$$Q=I_n-2\frac{(v-w)(v^t-w^t)}{\|v-w\|^2}$$

And now I should simplify this to a form that will help me, but I don't know how... any hints?

Comment: What happens if you apply your expression for $Q$ to $v$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to transform the product $w^Tv$ into an expression with norm-squares:
$$
(v^T-w^T)v = \|v\|^2 - w^Tv = \|v\|^2  + \frac12(\|v-w\|^2 - \|w\|^2 - \|v\|^2)
=\frac12\|v-w\|^2 .
$$